# Вывод двух новостей в одном слайде

Tags: php, wordpress, css3, html5, bootstrap

Мне нужно вывести две новости в слайдере, я переделал стандартный бутстраповский слайдер, но возник вопрос, как в цикле выводить по 2 новости из рубрики?
Вот код слайдера:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-10">
  <div id="carouselExampleControls2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 is-simple">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4 is-simple">
                          <img class="bottom-slider-img" src="/wp-content/themes/fish/img/img.jpg" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 bottom-slider-text bottom-slider">
                          <p class="is-orange-header is-simple">Рыба горячего копчения</p>
                          <span class="slider-text">Изготавливается только из свежей рыбы без добавления каких либо консервантов.</span><br />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4 is-simple">
                          <img class="bottom-slider-img" src="http://fish-wp/wp-content/themes/fish/img/img.jpg" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 bottom-slider-text bottom-slider">
                          <p class="is-orange-header is-simple">Рыба горячего копчения</p>
                          <span class="slider-text">Изготавливается только из свежей рыбы без добавления каких либо консервантов.</span><br />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно ли как-то адаптировать цикл wp под этот слайдер или нужно слайдер переделать?

Comment: Вы бы лучше код вывода приводили, а не готовую разметку слайдера.

Comment: @Pyramidhead так вот не знаю как его выводить) Я знаютолько как вывести одну новость но не 2(

Comment: Вы свой код вывода покажите, а тут вам скажут, как его исправить. Не писать же его за вас.

Comment: нажмите в вашем вопросе править - редактировать пример кода - и добавьте ваш код, сделайте пример воспроизводимым